# Attributes as dictionary values

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I am attempting to set attributes on a dict key and have a feeling my approach is wrong. How would I get the current key inside `alfa`? Alfa in production will be used to create and update a dataclass.

```
class Dictn(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(Dictn, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
        self.__dict__ = self

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key not in self.keys():
            self.__setitem__(key, None)
        dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        return self

    def alfa(self, **kwds):
        ''' Need current key to set attributes on it '''
        self.__setattr__(**kwds)

    def beta(self, **kwds):
        ''' Need current key to set attributes on it '''
        self.__setattr__(**kwds) 

dictn = Dictn()
dictn['ABC'].alfa(es=1, te=2)
dictn['ABC'].beta(es=3, te=4)
```

Comment: There is no "current key". The method has to be run on the dictionary, not a value from the dictionary.

Comment: What do you mean by 'current key'?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you want to achieve. Why does `__getitem__` return `self` and not a value from the dictionary?

Comment: What's the point of calling `dict.__getitem__(self, key)` and not using the result?

Comment: I'm trying to structure the data so that I have a dictionary with keys whose key attributes are Dataclasses. Ex. dictn['ABC'].alfa = dataclass, dictn['ABC'].beta = dataclass etc.

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary stores objects that can be recovered as key-value pairs. (Remember, everything in python is an object.) If you want those objects to have additional attributes, you need to edit them directly, not the `dict` class which only acts as a container. The dict doesn't really care what it stores, and it certainly isn't (and shouldn't be) responsible for handling any properties on its contents.

(By the way, `dictn["ABC"]` represents a *value* in the dictionary, not a *key*. They key here is `"ABC"`. I'm not sure if you're just confusing the definitions here or if you mean something else entirely.)

Answer (score 0):

You could set an instance variable to the key used in `__getitem__()`.

```
class Dictn(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(Dictn, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
        self.__dict__ = self

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key not in self.keys():
            self.__setitem__(key, None)
        self.current_key = key
        dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        return self

    def alfa(self, **kwds):
        // use self.current_key to get current_key to set attributes on it
        self.__setattr__(**kwds)

    def beta(self, **kwds):
        // use self.current_key to get current_key to set attributes on it
        self.__setattr__(**kwds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use a class as an attribute setter:

```py
@dataclass()
class Position:
    es: int = None
    te: int = None


class ValueObj():
    def alfa(self, **kwds):
        setattr(self, 'alfa', Position(**kwds))

    def beta(self, **kwds):
        setattr(self, 'beta', Position(**kwds))

class Dictn(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(Dictn, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
        self.__dict__ = self

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key not in self.keys():
            self.__setitem__(   key,
                                ValueObj(),
                            )
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
```

```py
dictn = Dictn()
dictn['ABC'].alfa(es=1, te=2)

dictn['ABC'].alfa
>> Position(es=1, te=2)
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69692473/3) to the question [Attributes as dictionary values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692473/attributes-as-dictionary-values) by the OP [misantroop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6301394/misantroop) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>